# MAMP not showing my Duplicator Pro downloaded WordPress website locally

Tags: local, mamp

I have downloaded my WordPress website (Perrellas.com) with Duplicator Pro to my Windows 10 computer. I have copied the two files to htdocs in Dropbox. I have installed MAMPS told it where the files are and have not been able to launch the website on my localhost.  HELP!

Before downloading my website I updated it to the latest WordPress and PHP. I see all Servers are green along with the cloud. When I click on Open WebStart page I get http://localhost/MAMP/.